# Can azure alerts rule be used for sending kusto query results on regular intervals?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-alerts

I have a requirement where I have to send kusto query results to different audience on a regular interval.
My current approach is setting up a azure function which runs and shares the query results with a mail service, which distributes it to the wider audience.

I was thinking if I can leverage azure alert rules for this task. I know we can set up custom log queries for azure data explorer, but can it be run so query results on one of the database's table(in ADX) can be  distributed?

Comment: What exactly do you mean regarding *db table data*?

Comment: @PeterBons, thank you for commenting, I have edited the details, this is the use case - We have few tables in one of the databases which are getting vendor data for external clients every day, now I want to filter previous day's vendor data on some conditions and share it with stakeholders.

Answer (score -1):

You can create KUSTO queries and then use azure alerts to send out results based on the query, another way it to use logic apps which can also run KUSTO queries and then send results to whatever you need and is probably better in this case since it's not really an alert if I understand you correctly you just want to run a query and distribute the result.

Just choose which the one that suits you best and try it out and if you end up with specific issues come back and ask specific questions and we will get you going.